# How to add constant column values in resultset of Solr Export handler?

Tags: solr

I am using solr export request handler (/export).I am  using solr version 5.2.
In the resultset of Solr export request(/export), Is it possible to add additional column with constant value for all rows?(i.e I would like to have column like 'serial number' with value of 1 for all rows returned). 
I tried with the below URL

[http://solrhost:8000/solr/corename/export?q=*:*&fl=name,sl_no[value%20v=1]&sort=name%20desc](http://solrhost:8000/solr/corename/exportq=*:*&fl=name,sl_no[value%20v=1]&sort=name%20desc)

and I get the below error

> java.io.IOException: sl_no:[value v=1] must have DocValues to use this
>   feature

.

I even tried adding sl_no field as docvalue ,but still not working.
The same URL works with '/select' request handler.

Comment: The DocumentTransformer-support is specific to the regular SearchHandler as far as I can see - there is nothing in the source for the ExportHandler that seems to indicate that its doing anything special with the fields from `fl`. Each field is resolved against the schema, so my guess is that `sl_no:[value v=1]` is processed literally as the field name. You can add a debugger and step through the [ExportWriter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/ExportWriter.java) if you want to dig further into this..

Comment: I could verify that sl_no:[value v=1] is taken literally in export request handler. I verified by giving the typo sl_no[valu v=1] and still got the same error. How to avoid this?

Comment: Seems you won't be able to use the /export handler to do what you're looking to do. You might be able to do it with streaming expressions though (which has a raw() function for literal values), or if necessary, use the regular SearchHandler with CSV as the output format or something similar.

Comment: could you please explain how to use raw() function for this scenario?. I tried to find, but could see solr documentation not helping.
I am using the stream URL http://solrhost:8000/solr/corename/stream?stream=search(corename,q=*:*,fl=field_name,sort=field_name asc,qt=/export)

Answer (score 0):

You do it by following the below instructions

1. First go to solr installation directory (you can find that by following command)

   `which solr`
2. then cd into that folder and then 
   navigate to the following path
   eg.

   `"./server/solr/<your-core-name>/conf/"`
3. open data-config.xml file in your favourite editor

   ```
   <entity name="my_table" query="SELECT '1' as serial_no, p_id, product_name  FROM `my_table`"> 
       <field column="p_id" name="p_id"/>
       <field column="product_name" name="product_name"/>
       <!-- Constant value column name which we specified in entity query above -->
       <field column="serial_no" name="serial_no"/>
   </entity>
   ```

**NOTE:**
Here we have included constant value column **serial_no** with **value as 1** by mentioning it in entity query attribute above in the **data-config.xml** file.

Comment: But this isn't the same - the question is about the /export handler functionality in Solr, and not about how to get a constant value from the Data Import Handler (which hasn't been mentioned at all).